# Checking whether spoken commands are enabled?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, macos-carbon, speech-recognition

Is there a way to check whether the user has enabled speech recognition (spoken commands) in System Preferences? (Mac OS X).  If the user has it enabled, I would like to support additional speech commands.  Unfortunately there isn't any method in `NSSpeechRecognizer` to check this and I can't seem to find any Carbon functions to check it either.

One of the problem is that the round Speech Commands window (the one with a microphone on it) seems to appear intermittently whenever I instantiate `NSSpeechRecognizer`. Also it often freezes my app for about half a second or so while the object is created (probably it's starting up the speech recognition service).

In essence, if the speech recognizer isn't already running and being used, I don't want to start it up.  But if the user actively uses the speech recognizer, I would like to provide additional support for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inspired by @`Yuji`'s answer, looks like the only way is to check whether the speech recognition server is running or not.  Here is the code snippet, in case anyone also need it.

```
+(BOOL) speakableItemsEnabled {
    NSString* speechServerBundleName = @"com.apple.speech.recognitionserver";
    NSArray* apps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:speechServerBundleName];
    NSRunningApplication* speechServerApp = [apps lastObject];
    return speechServerApp && !speechServerApp.terminated;
}
```

Hopefully this doesn't break in 10.7 "Lion".

Comment: OK then. It was somewhat derived from your answer though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the public API either; but the round mic window is controlled by `SpeakableItems.app`, at least on OS X 10.6. You can check the process list and/or the running applications list to see if it's there.

Comment: I couldn't find `SpeakableItems.app` in my installation, but the round window does come up.

Comment: It's buried deep inside the OS, have a look at `/System/Library/Speech/Recognizers/AppleSpeakableItems.SpeechRecognizer/Contents/Resources/`. It appears in the activity monitor.